# Realloc fails after the 10th iteration inside a loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to get a sequence of letters from the user, and put the input inside a dynamic array.

However, from a reason I can't quite figure out - realloc fails (returns NULL and "Error allocating memory!" is printed) if the user entered more than 10 letters. I did try to change realloc to calloc and that seems to solve it, but I'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *first_string, *second_string, *memory_check;
    char user_input;
    int first_string_size = 0, second_string_size = 0, debug =1;

    first_string = malloc(sizeof(char));
    second_string = malloc(sizeof(char));


    // gets the strings from the user

    printf("Input the first string:");

    for(int i = 0;;i++) {
        user_input= getchar();
        if(user_input == EOF || user_input == '\0' || user_input == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        first_string[i] = user_input;
        memory_check = realloc(first_string, (i+1)*(sizeof(char)));
        if(memory_check == NULL) {
            printf("\nError allocating memory!\n");
            break;
        }

        first_string_size = i;

        if(debug == 1) {
            printf("\n number of letters is %d", first_string_size +1);
            printf("\n array size in memory is %d", sizeof(first_string) * (i+1));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `perror` when printing errors, it gives more details. Change your `printf("Error alloc..` to `perror("realloc");`

Comment: Two unrelated hints: 1) Grow by a bigger amount than N+1, e.g. always double the size when the space is exhausted. 2) sizeof(char) is [defined to be 1](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf#page=108&zoom=auto,-133,792).

Comment: `memory_check` is the newly reallocated pointer, you need to trade this value with `first_string`.  `first_string` points to memory that has already now been freed (by realloc).

Answer (score 3):

of course it fails:

```
memory_check = realloc(first_string, (i+1)*(sizeof(char)));
    if(memory_check == NULL) {
        printf("\nError allocating memory!\n");
        break;
    }
```

you're using `memory_check` as a flag to check if you can reallocate, but it's not only that.

You *have* to assign it back to `first_string`.

In your case, it's a dead giveaway: the first 10 times (in your case, of course, this isn't specified or defined, it's pure random), the memory region doesn't need to be moved, which explain that it works. But after a while, `realloc` cannot reuse the same block (because it's too small) and it changes the memory location.

Since you're not updating it, you get undefined behaviour.

You could do this:

```
memory_check = realloc(first_string, (i+1)*(sizeof(char)));
if(memory_check == NULL) {
    printf("\nError allocating memory!\n");
    free(first_string);
    break;
}
first_string = memory_check;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to deallocated memory.

`memory_check` is the newly reallocated pointer, you need to trade this value with `first_string`. first_string points to memory that has already now been freed (by realloc)